# How int[] accepted as a Generic Type argument but not int?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, inheritance

I noticed that we can create Generic with type argument as `int[]` but not `int`.

I found out that a Type argument `T` to Generic `G<T>` should be a child of Object class.

Since primitive types are not the child of Object class so they cannot be used as argument types for generics.

But then I have a few doubts:

1. how can we use an array of primitive as a Generic type argument?
2. Do an Array of primitive/Reference types extends Object class?
3. Are Arrays a special Type of class that cannot be used as a normal class?
4. Are there any other special classes like arrays. (If the answer to this very broad then ignore this one)

I've looked around and found that Arrays are actually classes that extend Objects. (we create an array using the new keyword)

But I couldn't find answers to the rest of my questions.

Comment: `how can we use array of primitive then?` - use it for which purpose?

Comment: Is your first question meant to say "since primitives can't be used as generic types, why can we use arrays of primitive types as generic types?"

Comment: That is because an `int[]` is an object in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of a primitive type is an object indeed. Such an array can be used anywhere an object can be used. An array has a public `length` property, which returns the length of the array.

Arrays cannot be extended, but for any type `T` there exists a `T[]`. Arrays are more or less special, yes.

Another special class is the `Enum` class.

Answer (score 1):

There are two categories of types in java: primitive and reference(i.e. objects)

An [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) type (whether it's a primitive array or an object array) is always a reference type. A variable of array type holds a reference to an `object`.

An array of primitives is still an `Object`,
For example, `int[]` is a subtype of `Object`. You can call any methods in `Object` on an `int[]`.

Generics can hold anything that is not a primitive type. Arrays are not primitive types so `Collection<int[]>` is allowed. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html

Comment: "You can call any methods in Object on an int[]." is true, but they are all essentially useless (as in, the toString, equals, hashCode etc almost certainly don't do what you want).